# Magento 2.0 - Running additional code in a module after Product Save

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I **added additional fields to the Product New/Edit form** and need to save them onto a new table in the database as well as post the data onto another website store api.  **I have created the function to perform all of this** but, I am not sure how this should be called.  Should I hardcode the function call inside the Product Save execute() function? or should I use the Productsaveafter observer?  How can I get the post data inside the execute function of Productsaveafter observer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

We need to use RequestInterface to get post.

```
$post_data = $this->_request->getPost()->toArray();
```

**etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="Rahaha\RahahaWebService\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Productsaveafter.php**

```
<?php
namespace Rahaha\RahahaWebService\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;
    protected $_resource;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_rahaha;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $rahaha_username = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue("adminsample/rahaha_module_credentials_grp/rahaha_username", $storeScope);
        $rahaha_password = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue("adminsample/rahaha_module_credentials_grp/rahaha_password", $storeScope);
        $rahaha_api_key = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue("adminsample/rahaha_module_credentials_grp/rahaha_api_key", $storeScope);
        $rahaha_module_status = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue("adminsample/rahaha_module_status_grp/rahaha_module_status", $storeScope);

        $rs = $this->_resource;

        $this->_rahaha = new \Rahaha\RahahaWebService\Model\Rahaha\Rahaha($rahaha_username, $rahaha_password, $rahaha_api_key, $rahaha_module_status, $rs);
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $post_data = $this->_request->getPost()->toArray();

        //save stuff here...
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain line "//save stuff here..." - how to save data here?